# Customize list without InfoPath designer in SharePoint 2013 custom list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-list

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2013 , I want to customize it like the way we do in InfoPath designer without using the InfoPath Designer. Is it possible using any scripting or do I need to go for Visual Studio solution for this. Thanks for any suggestion on this.

Comment: Customise in what way? Add new columns? Order columns? Look and feel? It will depend on what customisations you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: hi SPChick I am looking to change look and feel. Add some background colors to the columns when the user opens to fill new form.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft InfoPath is a software that allows users to create complex electronic forms containing validation rules, actions, workflows and more. It supports users to build forms that supported calculations, external data sources, conditional formatting, and custom code inside the form itself.

Although do not know which function you want to use to customized your form, without using it, everything may be difficult. Maybe you can use code, but this may take lots of your time and effort.

Per my knowledge, there are some of the best InfoPath alternatives available for SharePoint, which may be useful to you(since you do not want to use InfoPath Designer). Refer to below article for more information:

https://sharegate.com/blog/5-alternatives-to-infopath-for-sharepoint-forms

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint Designer to modify the form. Not knowing the details of how you want to modify it diffident to say which tool is best for you.

It is possible to create a single page js application and then you can use the web services to make necessary calls to the API.

here are some good examples how to achieve that:
http://michaelsoriano.com/build-sharepoint-single-page-app-front-end-code/